# Sudden change of date in windows 7 (From 2013 to 2039)

Tags: windows-7, date

I was watching a video on youtube (using Chrome, OS is windows 7) when a pop up warned me that I had to calibrate my monitor again since the calibration was too old. This sounded strange, since I had done it yesterday, and I clicked it away to deal with it later. Then I locked the pc for some 30 minutes, and when I got back I found out some strange behaviour: facebook ssl certificate was expired, norton was disabled. I read with attention the error message of the ssl certificate and it was asking me if really today was may, 19th **2039**. I fixed the date, restarted the computer and now everything seems fine.

What could have caused this leap forward by 26 years? I am updating my backup since it doesn't seem a good sign, but I would like to know if there is some diagnostics/check which I could try to understand what's going on.

Let me know if you need further details.

**UPDATE**: I add some further details, I was using a not-elevated account, with Chrome with the Adblock plugin. I use the Norton av and all the latest windows protection updated were installed, AFAIK.

Comment: I would be suspicious that some malware used the date change to expose a vulnerability in the OS or browser.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I am suspicious, too. But it could be a sign of impending hardware failure, no?

Comment: It could simply indicate that the clock battery is failing, eg, but what better way to disable Norton, et al?

Comment: Daniel: they were duly disabled. But I was able to restore the date without any "apparent impediment", as soon as I tried it.

Comment: Yeah, once the malware's been installed (and permanently disabled Norton) there's no need to use the date trick anymore.  Just sayin' ...

Comment: (If it happens again it's probably just your battery or whatever.  I'd be more worried if it DOESN'T happen again.)